# Debugging Hashed Results: Lengths, Arrays, Chars

Tags: c, arrays, string, hash, hex

Do these results make sense?

I am trying to understand how mhash works, but does anyone know how these results make sense??

mac is a char, and based on strlen its length is 16 
however, this sample program provided by mhash outputs the following hash which is in hexadecimal format (.x)
750c783e6ab0b503eaa86e310a5db738
And the length of this mac[i] is twice the size of 16, anyone have any idea on why this might be?

```
// output result
// 0x750c783e6ab0b503eaa86e310a5db738 (MD5) (32)
// mac length: 16
// md5 length: 16

#include <mhash.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char password[] = "Jefe";
    int keylen = 4;
    char data[] = "what do ya want for nothing?";
    int datalen = 28;

    MHASH td;
    unsigned char *mac;
    int i, j;

    td = mhash_hmac_init(MHASH_MD5, password, keylen, mhash_get_hash_pblock(MHASH_MD5));

    mhash(td, data, datalen);
    mac = mhash_hmac_end(td);

    int md5len = mhash_get_block_size(MHASH_MD5);

    printf("0x");
    for (i = 0; i < md5len; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2x", mac[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // I don't understand how the mac is a different size than the version printed out!?
    printf("%x\n", mac);

    int maclen = strlen(mac);
    printf("mac length: %d\n", maclen);
    printf("md5 length: %d\n", md5len);

    exit(0);
}
```

Also, if I try to output mac using printf like the following:

```
printf("%x\n", mac);
```

I would get this:

```
u
 x>j����n1
]�8
```

The API for mhash can be found here: http://mhash.sourceforge.net/mhash.3.html

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Hint: the hexadecimal representation of a single byte is two hex digits long.

Comment: You can't print an array of bytes as %x. You must loop through your data and print each byte individually (better as %02x).

Comment: printf(..., mac) will take de address of the first byte of mac array. And %x will try to print it in hex. Your output seems to me more like a %s, given it has exactly 16 bytes (supposing each newline adds just one byte, the '\n').

Comment: Also note that `strlen(mac)` is probably undefined (I don't know mhash specifically, but most probably it is undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't take `mac` as a string (either as array of char or pointer to first char of a string).

`mac` is to be read as an array of bytes, whose size is known in advance (the result of `mhash_get_block_size`).

`strlen(mac)` is undefined. Only by chance you'll get the right size (think of a hash that happens to have a zero byte: it will end the wanna-be-string prematurely).

Comment: Ok, great thank you, so think of mac as an array of bytes, got it! So, basically, if I want to know it's length than all I have to do is multiple the block size by 2?

Comment: No. It's size is **exactly** blocksize. You must understand separately the size of your hash (for MD5 it's 16 bytes) and the length of its rendidion to characters.

Comment: It's hexadecimal representation is twice that size, **because** each byte takes two hexadecimal digits (from 00 to ff).

Comment: Also, any idea on what the password and key might be for? I know this is not really part of the question, but it would be great if I could have some input, I will be looking into why we need those two attributes

Comment: If you where to represent the hash (16 bytes = 128 bits) in [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (another encoding where each digit can represent 6 bits), then it would take 22 chars (the last one only partially).

Comment: That was referring to the password and key?

Comment: password **is** the key. About the `keylen` variable, it is just `sizeof password - 1` (-1 to take away the automatic `\0`). You're not actually computing MD5 (in the sense of a clear MD5 checksum), but an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) that [**uses** MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC#Examples_of_HMAC_.28MD5.2C_SHA1.2C_SHA256.29) to sign the data. The key (or `password` here) is the piece of information that should be kept secret in order to guarantee that your data were not touched (otherwise the hash signature will be different).